# how to implement virtual along with async loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I am using async loop to loop through the given result, when I am doing that I am unable to get the virtual key "name" in the iteration.**

Any solution is welcome, I am stuck with this issue.

var result_subscriptions_of_user    = _.where(data.subscription_details, {'user_id': subscription_detail.user_id});

// value are coming in   result_subscriptions_of_user

// Iterate through the user subscription details

async.eachSeries(result_subscriptions_of_user, function iteratee(subscription_user_detail, callback) 
                        {
//here subscription_user_detail is not comming

what wrong i am doing here

**my schema is** 
var subscription_schema     = new db.schema({

subscription_id     : Number,

created_on                          : { type: Date, default: Date.now },

created_by                          : object_id,

provisioned_on                      : Date,

expiry_date                         : Date,

status                              : String,

},
{toObject: {virtuals: true,getters:true },toJSON: {virtuals: true,getters:true }});

**and my virtual function is**

```
subscription_schema.virtual('actual_expiry_date').get(function () 
{ 
    var moment          = require('moment-timezone');
    var date            = moment(this.expiry_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'); 
    return date;  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the resulting record is converted to an object or JSON, virtuals are not included by default. Pass virtuals : true to either toObject() or to toJSON() to have them returned. You need set userSchema like this

```
userSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
```

check this [document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Comment: i had done that  but when i an using  <br> var result_subscriptions_of_user  = _.where(data.subscription_details, {'user_id': subscription_detail.user_id});  // value are cooming here
      // Iterate through the user subscription
      async.eachSeries(result_subscriptions_of_user, function iteratee(subscription_user_detail, callback) 
      { // but here subscription_user_detail value are not commingwhat wrong i am doing

Comment: where you define userSchema

Comment: var subscription_schema  = new db.schema({
subscription_id  : Number,
created_on       : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
created_by        : object_id,
provisioned_on       : Date,
expiry_date       : Date, 
status           : String,

},{toObject: {virtuals: true,getters:true },toJSON: {virtuals: true,getters:true }});